# Is there a way to loop through an entire Python script with an Input function?

Tags: python

I have a very basic Blackjack simulator where I input whether I want to Hit or Stay. When I choose it, it then tells me the result. I want to run this over multiple times. Is there a function where after I get the result of the hand, it will restart from the top of the script?

I am using Jupyter notebook and am currently just restarting and running all cells and then input my choice

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code.

Comment: A "while True: " loop might do the trick

Comment: Wrap your logic in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic game play pattern such as the following to do what you want.

```
# Function to request input and verify input type is valid
def getInput(prompt, respType= None):
    while True:
        resp = input(prompt)
        if respType == str or respType == None:
            break
        else:
            try:
                resp = respType(resp)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid input, please try again')
    return resp  

# function to initiate game play and control game termination
def playgame():
    if getInput('Do you want to play? (y/n)').lower() == 'y':
            while True:
                game_input = getInput('Enter an Integer', int)
                # . . .  Place your game logic here . . . #
                if getInput("Play Again? (y/n)").lower() == 'n':
                    break
    print('Good bye')
```